# bash- How can I remove the whole line of a txt file if its 2nd word is lower than X?

Tags: bash

I have a txt file like:

```
apple 200

orange 100

banana 10
```

in the output I want he lines with number lower than 20:

```
apple 200

orange 100
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To make it easier for us to answer your question, it would help if you provided some more information. What have you tried? What error did you get? Can you provide a short, self-contained example of the problem you are seeing? See http://sscce.org, http://whathaveyoutried.com, and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for details on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$2>=20' file
apple 200
orange 100
```

Comment: thank you it works, but I think I should use awk '$2>20' file

Comment: Sure but `'$2>20'` will also skip lines with number 20.

Comment: Also if it worked out can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Answer this simple command only for vote from a 138K account. Why help like this way. LOL.

Comment: That's probably exactly how to reach 138k rep. Smirk.

Comment: Using same yardstick I can point fingers at so many answers here even from users double than my rep. Point is one can't control complexity (or simplicity) of the question. Answer will be as good (OR as simple) as the question being asked.